# How do I load another HTML page inside a JQuery UI Dialog box?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to make an HTML page appear inside of a JQuery UI Modal form for collecting data. Other solutions online told me to do something like this:

```
var scanDialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    "Scan": function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                  }
                });

             scanDialog.load(url).dialog('open');
```

This doesn't work and just loads an empty dialog box. What is the correct way to load a page into a dialog box?

The HTML page I am trying to load is 2 levels up in the directory structure. Is the correct way to get the url this: '../page.html'?

Comment: please post your html code too

Comment: What you have should work, confirm that ../page.html is the correct path.

Comment: try using firebug and check if the call is throwing 200 ok or 404 error

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

you just need to creat a html element with `id=dialog`

for example:

```
<div id="dialog">
//some other stuff here
</div>
```